# Magento 2 - moving search box to Navigation area

Tags: magento2, catalogsearch, theme-overriding

I want to **move search box** to the **right side of category lists** on top navigation menu:

[image]

I've added the following line in `Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml` which moved search box to the desired position ( image above is the result ) :

```
<move element="top.search" destination="catalog.topnav" before="-" />
```

However, when I click on the box to insert text the cursor jumps out of focus immediately. But if I **right click into the box -> paste data** there and press Enter or magnifier icon, search function still work.

What else do I need to add to my code to make it work, or is there another solution?

Comment: could you just provide link of your site or any screenshot to elaborate it. So it would be better to understand?

Comment: I've added the image, thank you. Site link is http://35.197.145.89/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your search is working but not letting you click into it because one class is added into it that is **`ui-menu-item`** & that because it is been added into `catalog.topnav` block.So the **js** **`(menu.js)`** of this adds **`ui-menu-item`** to it look the below code **(You can check it by inspect element in your browser)**.

```
<div class="block block-search ui-menu-item" role="presentation">
```

When you remove class **`ui-menu-item`** from this dive it will work but it is not feasible there when you add this to the **`catalog.topnav`** so better would be add this code into your default.xml file

```
<move element="top.search" destination="store.menu" after="catalog.topnav"/>
```

Instead of the code you added to it & just target your `<div class="block block-search">` there & add a `css` for it like this

```
.block.block-search {display: block;}
```

For better look & feel do adjust it with your own `css`.

> Note: While you are doing this make sure your cache is disable or run
>   the below command to see the output
>
> Do this changes by creating your own theme instead of editing the core files 
>   it is not a best practice for magento development.
>
> ```
> php bin/magento cache:flush
> ```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I'm confused about the second part: how and where can I add a `css` file that targets `<div class="block block-search"> ?` ( I've created my own theme which inherits from magento blank ).

Comment: simply in your theme you can create your own css into your web/css folder & pass it's reference link into your `default_head_blocks.xml` file of your theme that is located at `app/design/frontend/{vendor}/{theme}/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml`

Answer (score 0):

1. Edit default.xml

app/design/frontend/Vendor_Name/Theme_Name/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

Example

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
         <move element="top.search" destination="store.menu" after="-" />
</body>
</page>
```

2. Flush Magento cache.

Note:-
If it still doesn't work then you can remove the block and add it again

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>

        <referenceBlock name="top.search" remove="true"/>

        <referenceContainer name="store.menu">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="top.search.nav" as="topSearchNav" template="Magento_Search::form.mini.phtml" after="-" />
        </referenceContainer>

    </body>
</page>
```